# How to represent a 2D matrix in Java?

Tags: java, matrix, data-structures

I have to create in Java a 2D matrix (consisting of double values) as well as a 1D vector. It should be possible to access individual rows and columns as well as individual elements. Moreover, it should be thread-safe (threads writing at the same time). Perhaps later I need some matrix operations too.

Which data structure is best for this? Just a 2D array or a TreeMap? Or is there any amazing external library?

Comment: You need both rows *and* columns? That's sort of having it both ways. It can be done of course, but if you can at all avoid it it would be a lot easier

Comment: `Object[][] matrix = new Object[rowLen][colLen];` rowLen and colLen are values you have to set it **previously**. Of course, you can change Object to String, Integer, Long, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use Vector for 2D array. It is **threadsafe**.

```
Vector<Vector<Double>>  matrix= new Vector<Vector<Double>>();

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        Vector<Double> r=new Vector<>();
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
            r.add(Math.random());
        }
        matrix.add(r);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        Vector<Double> r=matrix.get(i);
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
            System.out.print(r.get(j));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

If this is your  matrix indexes

00 01

10 11

You can get specifix index value like this

```
Double r2c1=matrix.get(1).get(0); //2nd row 1st column
```

Have a look at
[Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Comment: Thank you but how can I easy access a whole column or row?

Comment: A particular row can be obtained by accessing [Get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#get(int)) method over matrix.

Any particular column cannot be obtained directly. You must build it using indexes.

Comment: You can do better than this.

Answer (score 13):

I'll give you an example:

```
int rowLen = 10, colLen = 20;   
Integer[][] matrix = new Integer[rowLen][colLen];
for(int i = 0; i < rowLen; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < colLen; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = 2*(i + j); // only an example of how to access it. you can do here whatever you want.
```

Clear?

Answer (score 5):

If you need thread safe behavior, use

```
Vector<Vector<Double>> matrix = new Vector<Vector<Double>>();
```

If you don't need thread safe behavior, use

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
```