# Reading files that contains different dimensions for a 2D array

Tags: java, file, matrix, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I am trying to read text files. The files go like this:

> The first line is the number of grids
>
> The second line is the m x n matrix
>
> And then we have the elements for the cells and then it goes onto another m x n matrix on another line and then its elements and so on.

The sample pic would clarify my description further.

Now i know how to use `Scanner` and read files but the problem is i am hardcoding the matrix dimensions where as i want an algorithm that can work on any file. The files are going to be the same only the dimensions will change.

Right now my algorithm looks like this:

```
 Get the name of the file as command line argument
 then read the first line which is the number of grids to create
 then read the next line which states the dimension of the first grid
 then create a 2D array of that dimension. 
 Then read only lines up to the rows specified and load the data
 Then read the dimensions for the next grid and loop on till the end.
```

Now it is easy to get the algorithm but i don't know how i would translate that into workable code. I am able to use `Scanner` and i also know `BufferedReader` but i would prefer `Scanner` as it contains more functions. My question is how should i go about processing files with different matrices dimensions and number of grids.

[One example of a test file to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwoG4.png)

Comment: _"Now it is easy to get the algorithm but i don't know how i would translate that into workable code"_ -- Why not? Are you expecting us to write the code for you?  Sorry, but that's not how this site works.  Questions of the form _"I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code"_ are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: My does not ask about tips or sample code, i just asked how should i go about processing the different files, an algorithm that works for all files and not just one. The algorithm that i have is hardcoded for the sample file that i have at the bottom of my question. I already have a code that works for one file but i'll be reading different files and the algorithm i have will not work for them. So what adjustments can i make to this algorithm, that was my question @JimGarrison

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the matrix elements (i.e. the numbers in a matrix) in the input file need to be separated. The matrix elements in your sample image aren't and that can cause problems (e.g. using your current approach for input file format, there's no way to distinguish the matrices [1 11] and [11 1]).

You can implement your algorithm with the *getArrayOfMatrices* method below; this method takes the input file name as a parameter and returns an array of the 2D array representations of the matrices. You can access (where a represents the array that the method returns):
(1) the 2D array for the first matrix with `a[0]`
(2) the 2D array for the second matrix with `a[1]`
(3) the (1, 1)-entry of the first matrix with `a[0][0][0]`
(4) the (1, 2)-entry of the first matrix with `a[0][0][1]`
(5) the (2, 1)-entry of the first matrix with `a[0][1][0]`
(6) the (2, 2)-entry of the first matrix with `a[0][1][1]`
(7) the (1, 1)-entry of the second matrix with `a[1][0][0]`
(8) the (1, 2)-entry of the second matrix with `a[1][0][1]`
(9) the (2, 1)-entry of the second matrix with `a[1][1][0]`
(10) the (2, 2)-entry of the second matrix with `a[1][1][1]`
etc.

For the approach that is taken with this code, there's the assumption that the matrix elements in the input file are separated by a space.

Here's an example of input file content that can be used with the *getArrayOfMatrices* method:
2
1 1
2
2 3
-1 0 1
3 30 300

Here's the method code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ObtainmentOfArrayOfMatrices {

    public static int[][][] getArrayOfMatrices(String inputFileName)
    throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
        int numberOfMatrices = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        // An array that will contain all the 2D array representations of the
        // matrices.
        int[][][] arrayOfMatrices = new int[numberOfMatrices][][];

        int numberOfMatricesGoneOver = 0;
        while(numberOfMatricesGoneOver < numberOfMatrices) {

            // Create a 2D array representation of the current matrix and put
            // that representation in an array.

            String[] dimensions = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            int numberOfRows = Integer.parseInt(dimensions[0]);
            int numberOfColumns = Integer.parseInt(dimensions[1]);

            // A 2D array which represents the current matrix.
            int[][] currentMatrix = new int[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];

            int numberOfRowsGoneOver = 0;
            while(numberOfRowsGoneOver < numberOfRows) {

                // An array that represents the current matrix row.
                int[] currentRow = new int[numberOfColumns];

                String[] elementsInCurrentRow = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
                int numberOfColumnsGoneOverInCurrentRow = 0;

                // Insert the elements that are in the current matrix row.
                while(numberOfColumnsGoneOverInCurrentRow < numberOfColumns) {
                    currentRow[numberOfColumnsGoneOverInCurrentRow] = 
                    Integer.parseInt(elementsInCurrentRow
                    [numberOfColumnsGoneOverInCurrentRow]);
                    numberOfColumnsGoneOverInCurrentRow++;
                }

                // Insert the complete array representation of the current
                // matrix row.
                currentMatrix[numberOfRowsGoneOver] = currentRow;

                numberOfRowsGoneOver++;
            }

            // At this point, there's a complete 2D array representation of
            // the current matrix.

            arrayOfMatrices[numberOfMatricesGoneOver] = currentMatrix;
            numberOfMatricesGoneOver++;
        }
        scanner.close();
        return arrayOfMatrices;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Start by declaring a matrix at the beginning of the program:

```
int[][] matrix;
int n,m;
for each matrix on the file:
    read matrix dimensions to n and m
    matrix = new int[n][m]
    read values and put them on matrix
```

Other alternatives can be declaring a `Vector<Vector<Integer>>` like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240044/how-to-represent-a-2d-matrix-in-java) or having a class representing a matrix like [this one](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/95linear/Matrix.java.html).

Comment: How is this one different than my algorithm? You basically repeated what i had in my algorithm.

Comment: Then i'm not understanding exactly what you want. You said the problem is that you were hardcoding the matrix dimensions on your code. With the solutions i presented you, you don't need to hardcode the dimensions. If anything you are just hardcoding the type of the elements on the matrix.